# Determine ASP.NET Core MVC Area during service registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

- I'm using ASP.NET Core
- My `IService` is registered with the DI container
- There are two implementations: `FooService` and `BarService`
- I must choose a service based on current request's MVC Area

So I need something like:

```
services.AddScoped<IService>(
    c => IsThisTheFooArea
        ? c.GetRequiredService<FooService>() as IService
        : c.GetRequiredService<BarService>() as IService
);
```

I don't know how to implement the `IsThisTheFooArea` check.

How do I access the `HttpContext` or something similar, so I can inspect the current route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

ConfigureServices.cs:

```
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<IService>(provider =>
        {
            var actionContextAccessor = provider.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>();
            var descriptor = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
            var areaName = descriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>().RouteValue;
            if(areaName == "FooArea")
            {
                return new FooService();
            }
            else
            {
                return new BarService();
            }
        });
```

Services:

```
public interface IService { string DoThisThing(); }

public class FooService : IService
{
    public string DoThisThing()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

public class BarService : IService
{
    public string DoThisThing()
    {
        return "Bar";
    }
}
```

And controllers:

```
[Area("FooArea")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public FooController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(_service.DoThisThing());
    }
}

[Area("BarArea")]
public class BarController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public BarController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(_service.DoThisThing());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. (...but wow, so many hoops to jump through for something so simple.)

Comment: Also, I recall reading on the github project page that `ActionContextAccessor` is not registed by default as it's expensive, so it's a pity there is no easier way. It works though, which is good enough for my needs.

Comment: It is required for getting area info. I don't know if there is another way to get area name. Request path(area part) may be used but in this case you will need to inject `HttpContextAccessor` and i think it is not good way.

Comment: Why do you think `HttpContextAccessor` is a "bad" way?

Comment: No, i don't mean using `HttpContextAccessor` is bad, i think the "request path" way is bad for your case.

Answer (score -1):

You need to either implement (or find an implementation based on) IControllerFactory or IDependencyResolver and set it at application startup in order to inject the controller dependencies.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory(container));

// Or...

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MyDependencyResolver(container));
```

More info
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: That is not for Core. Also, I don't need to inject into controllers.